# list the devices associated with logical volumes under without using lvm2 package commands

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, logical-drive

I want to list all the physical volume associated with logical volume.

I know `lvdisplay, pvscan ,pvdisplay -m` could do the job .but I dont want to use this command.
Is there any other way to do it without using lvm2 package commands?

Any thoughts on comparing `Major and Minor number` of device?

Answer (score 0):

What about `system-config-lvm`:

https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/s1-system-config-lvm.html

Answer (score 0):

If you know the Volume Group (possibly depending on your distro, it works for me under Ubuntu 12.04) you can discern the LV's by looking in /dev/mapper the block devices are all there, using a "-" to seperate the VG from the LV.  I suspect this is an imperfect solution if, for example, you have other devices - I have 1 other virtual device, but its obvious which one it is, both by the name and because it doesn't have a "-"